# Pixel segmentation loss function in TensorFlow low, but output wrong?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, convolution

I am trying to use pixel-wise two class segmentation (foreground/background) to achieve object detection using CNN in TensorFlow. I am using binary object masks as groundtruth. As a very simple case I am using synthetically generated dataset with grayscale images, black background 3 lines and one rectangle. My goal is to detect a rectangle. Example of my input and output are given below.

Input (320x240):

[image]
[image]

Output (20x15):
[image]
[image]

My network is fully convolutional, with last layer having size [20x15x2]. Each of these 2 feature maps represents probability of pixel belonging to respective class.

This is how I'm computing loss function:

```
reshaped_logits = tf.reshape(pred, [-1, 2])  # shape [batch_size*20*15, 2]
reshaped_labels = tf.reshape(y, [-1])  # shape [batch_size*20*15]

loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(reshaped_logits, reshaped_labels)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(loss)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

My loss function converges to a minimum of:
`Minibatch Loss= 0.693147` quite fast, even though my output is really wrong. This is how I am computing the predicted mask in one iteration:

```
t = tf.nn.softmax(reshaped_logits) # from code snipped above
prob_maps = tf.reshape(t, [-1, out_size[0], out_size[1], 2]) # out_size=(20,15)
t = tf.cast(tf.argmax(prob_maps, 3), tf.int32)
out = tf.reshape(t, [-1, out_size[0], out_size[1]])
```

The output I'm getting for this groundtruth:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

... is this:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Is it possible that my model does converge properly but that I am somehow computing the output in a wrong way?

Comment: It looks like your model yields one-hot encoding. One of possible reasons is that logits that are fed to softmax cross entropy have very large magnitude. I would suggest to examine max and min of `pred`. Do you do any regularization and/or normalization?

Comment: In the first couple of iterations they are in range [0, 10^4] and very quickly decline to 0 (both min and max). Lowering learning rate decreases the speed of decline, of course, but they still do decline. I do not do any regularization nor normalization, I have 3 successive covolution + bias + ReLU + max pooling layers and one convolution layer at the end (mentioned in question). Is it possible that ReLU is exploding because it's unbounded?

Comment: Adding L2 normalization after each ReLU layer brings both feature maps of pred layer to be [0, 1.0]. Result is still messy (doesn't converge to proper one-hot label) and loss is slightly oscillating in range [0.64, 0.65] between successive batches.

Comment: Do you apply `relu` to final layer? If so, try to remove it. Final layer usually does not have any activation function. In fact, `softmax` acts usually as activation function for the final layer.